# Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all finite linear combinations $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{-\lambda_j x}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=[0,\infty]$ be the one-point compactification of $[0,\infty)$, the non-negative real numbers with the usual metric. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all finite linear combinations 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{-\lambda_j x}$$
where $a_j$ are real and each $\lambda_j\geq 0$.

> (1) Prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a dense subset of $C(X)$.

For (1), my original idea is wrong. To use Stone-Weierstrass theorem, check:

(i) $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra. For $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{-\lambda_j x}$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m b_j e^{-\lambda_j x}$. Clearly, $fg\in \mathcal{A}$.

(ii) Separates points: for every $x, y\in X$, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then 
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j (e^{-\lambda_j x}-e^{-\lambda_j y})$$.
Since $a_j\neq 0$, then $e^{-\lambda_j x}-e^{-\lambda_j y}=0$. So $x=y$.

(iii) Vanishes at no points: For $a_j\neq 0$, $e^{-\lambda_j x}>0$.

> (2) Prove that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two continuous integrable functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at infinity and which have the same Laplace transform, that is 
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} f_1(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} f_2(x)dx$$ for all $\lambda \geq 0$, then $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x$.

I feel like we need to use (1) to show (2). But I have no idea.

Comment: For the concrete elementary proof : for $f\in C([0,\infty])$ let $g(y) = f(-\log( \min(1,|y|)))$ it is continuous and bounded on $\Bbb{R}$ thus $g_n(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t) n e^{-\pi n^2 (y-t)^2}dt$ approaches it locally uniformly, the $g_n$ are analytic so we can approach them on $[-1,1]$ by their Taylor expansions $G_{n,K_n}(y)=\sum_{k\le K_n} \frac{g_n^{(k)}(0)}{k!} y^k$ and $G_{n,K_n}(e^{-x})-G_{n,K_n}(0)$ approaches $f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Part 1): This is an immediate consequence of Stone-Wierstrass Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

$[0,\infty]$ is a compact Hausdorff space and your family is an algebra which separates points and vanishes at no point. Hence it is dense in $C(X)$.

For Part 2) just note that $\int_0^{\infty} g(f_1-f_2) =0$ for all $g \in C(X)$ by part 1). [You will need integrability of $f_1$ and $f_2$ here]. Put $ g=f_1-f_2$ to finish the proof.

Comment: For (1): Can I check: (i)A  is an algebra (ii) Separates points (iii) Vanishes at no points? Why do we need to check that contains constants?

Comment: For(1), I write my solution. Is it right?

Comment: For(2), I know that $\int g(f_1-f_2)=0$ for every $g\in \mathcal{A}$.  But why it also holds for $g\in C(\mathcal{A})$? Why we can let $g=f_1-f_2$?

Comment: @BobOakley To say that the algebra separates points you need take an arbitrary linear combination. If $x \neq y$ then $e^{-x} \neq e^{-y}$ and that is enough.

Comment: Okay, you mean let $g=\sum_{j=1}^{m} b_je^{-\lambda_j x}?$

Comment: @BobOakley Given $g \in C(X)$ take $h \in \mathcal A$such that $\|g-h\|<\epsilon$. Use the inequality $\int (g-h) (f_1-f_2) | \leq \epsilon \int |f_1-f_2|$. We can take $g=f_1-f_2$ because this function belongs to $C(X)$.

Comment: So there exists $g$ such that $f_1-f_2=g$, then $\int_0^{\infty} (f_1-f_2)^2=0$. So f_1=f_2 a.e.?

Comment: @BobOakley $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous. So we actually get $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for every $x$, not just a.e..